# search the word in linq to sql?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Table **users**:

```
userid     username 
------------------------------------
1          venkatesh duggirala
2          deviprasad  
3          dhanu
```

if user sends   username="d" then need to get all records.by using "contains" i am getting 2,3 as result.but 1st record also having "d" in duggirala.

query:

```
var result = from p in cxt.users
             where p.Users.username.Contains(name) 
             select new
             {
                 p.Userid
             };
```

Comment: Can you post how your query code looks like?

Comment: Assuming username is a string, all three results should be returned by your current query.

Comment: all that i can see is that contains is written with uppercase Contains(name)

but are you sure that a username is venkatesh duggirala and not simply venkatesh? just wondering because a space is not common in a username.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your query like this:

```
var result = from p in cxt.users 
         where p.Users.username.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())  
         select new 
         { 
             p.Userid 
         };
```